# How do I add multiple ranges in excel, to prevent duplicate entries

Tags: excel, duplicates, range

I am trying to stop duplicate entries in several columns, from a drop down list. I have it working for the first column, but when I try and add a range for columns C2:C9, D2:D9 and E2:E9 I get errors. This is the code I have for B2:B9, can anyone tell me how to add more ranges? Each column uses the same list for entries. It is a simple list of numbers 1 to 8. I want each column to be able to score 1 to 8, without duplicating the score in the individual column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B9"), Target) > 1 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Undo
Application.EnableEvents = True
MsgBox "Duplicate score. Please select a different value."
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `Target.Column`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(2, Target.Column), Cells(9, Target.Column))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(2, Target.Column), Cells(9, Target.Column)), Target) > 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Duplicate score. Please select a different value."
End If

End Sub
```

It will work for any column in rows 2:9.

Comment: That is great! Thank you so much, it works perfectly!

Comment: @HiResCovers No Problem! Could you mark as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("B2:E9")
    If Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, Target) > 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        MsgBox "Duplicate score. Please select a different value."
    End If
End Sub
```

The code would be slightly different if the columns were disjoint.